# Webscraping Excel beginner issue: Object required

Tags: excel, vba

I am developing a webscraper.
Code as follows :

```
'============ Module 1 ======================

Sub test()

Dim eRow As Long
Dim ele As Object

Set sht = Sheets("Sheet1")
RowCount = 1
sht.Range("A" & RowCount) = "Title"
sht.Range("B" & RowCount) = "Company"
sht.Range("C" & RowCount) = "Location"
sht.Range("D" & RowCount) = "Description"

eRow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row

Set objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

myjobtype = InputBox("Enter type of job eg. sales, admin  ")
myzip = InputBox("Enter zipcode of area where you wish to work")

With objIE
    .Visible = False
    .navigate "http://www.jobs.com/"

Do While .Busy Or _
    .readyState <> 4
DoEvents
Loop

Set what = .document.getElementsByName("q")
what.Item(0).Value myjobtype

Set zipcode = .document.getElementsByName("where")
zipcode.Item(0).Value = myzip

'*====================================================*
.document.getElementByld("JobsButton").Click
'*=====================================================*


Do While .Busy Or _
    .readyState <> 4
DoEvents
Loop

For Each ele In .document.all

    Select Case ele.classname
    Case "Result"
    RowCount = RowCount + 1
    Case "Title"
    sht.Range("A" & RowCount) = ele.innertext
    Case "Company"
    sht.Range(B & RowCount) = ele.innertext
    Case "Location"
    sht.Range("C" & RowCount) = ele.innertext
    Case "Description”"
    sht.Range("D" & RowCount) = ele.innertext

End Select
Next ele
End With

Macro1

Set objIE = Nothing

End Sub
```

'======================Module 2=======================

```
Sub Macro1()

' Macrol Macro
' Formatting imported data

Columns("A:D").Select
Selection.Columns.AutoFit
With Selection
     .VerticalAlignment = xlTop
     .Orientation = 0
     .Addlndent = False
     .IndentLevel = 0
     .ShrinkToFit = False
     .ReadingOrder = xlContext
End With
Range("D1").Select
Columns("D:D").ColwmnW1dth = 50
Columns("A:D").Select
Selection.Rows.AutoFit
End Sub
```

'============================================================

The issue with this code is that previously there was an id for clicking the button but now they have removed the id.  I tried replacing the content within *===* with many examples without success most of the time the error was "object required" for other suggestions I used from this site.  Can someone please help me replace the part within *===* that clicks the button..

The HTML for the button on that site now is changed to

```
<button type="submit" class="btn">Search Now</button>
```

=============================================================
This is how the code works : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cSoRVZKRkvY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.document.getElementsByTagName("button")(0)` should be able to capture the search button

And I have done more for you. Use the following piece of code after `.document.getElementsByTagName("button")(0).click`

```
Set resultset = .document.getElementsByTagName("article")
RowCount = 2
For Each result In resultset
    sht.Range("A" & RowCount) = result.ChildNodes(0).innertext
    sht.Range("B" & RowCount) = result.ChildNodes(1).innertext
    sht.Range("C" & RowCount) = result.ChildNodes(2).innertext
    sht.Range("D" & RowCount) = result.ChildNodes(3).innertext
    RowCount = RowCount + 1
Next
```

Comment: thanks .. i'l try working it out and let you know .. was eagerly searchig web for answer since i posted :D

Comment: I tried that actually, but then your code seems to be too heavy after that search. You are looping through every element in the HTMLDocument...

Comment: Code updated. However, your search result is split into different pages. You need more complicated codes to capture all the results.

Comment: hi @sam092 .. thankyou so much for your efforts .. i used ur updated code to get through the issues .. now everything seems to be working fine .. i have a few examples from stackoverflow that will help me loop through the webpage results ... 
And yes the code is a bit heavier with so many results but i dont mind since it is for generally for once in a week use  .. :) Once again thanks for your effort .. will post the project here once done .. all credits to you .. :)

Comment: @AdityaPednekar No problem :) Feel free to raise other problems